# web.config masking url and all links inside all the html pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a domain on which I have WordPress blog.
**example.com/folder/blog/**

I want that it should be accessible under the following url
**example.com/partnerdata/** ....which I managed to did it by writing a rule in web.config file as below

```
<rule name="maskingrule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^partnerdata/?(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.example.com/folder/blog/" />
 </rule>
```

But the problem is that all the links on the page still points to https://www.example.com/folder/blog/ even when the browser shows example.com/partnerdata/. E.G browser loads example.com/partnerdata/page1
but the hrefs on page1 are still pointing to https://www.example.com/folder/blog/page1.

I want that all the links should automatically be mapped to /folder/blog but all the links should point to /partnerdata instead of /fodler/blog

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite rule wont change the url on the html.
Rewrite will make when the users type the url "example.com/partnerdata/" on his browser to see the content on www.example.com/folder/blog.
You will need to change the url in the pages to the desired ones.

Comment: but if I do that wordpress will cause issues...I dont want to change wordpress urls